# PHP no ejecuta mi query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy verificando que si existe un usuario con un correo ya no deje usar ese correo para registrarse y le envíe un error, pero si no está registrado que le permita registrarse (lo hago a través de un stored procedure en MySQL) pero si entra al else hace todo lo demás menos ejecutar la query.

¿Cuál es el error que no estoy viendo?

```
try {    
        $sql = "call planevento.verificarCorreoCliente('$correo');";
        $resultado = $conn->query($sql);
        $rows = $resultado->num_rows;
        if ($rows > 0) {
            $respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => 'existe'
            );
            $resultado->close();
            $conn->close();
        } else {
            if (!is_dir($directorio)) {
                mkdir($directorio, 0755, true);
            }
        
            if (move_uploaded_file($imagen, $directorio . $nombreImagen )) {
                $imagenResultado = 'Se subio';
            }else{
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => error_get_last()
                );
            }
        
            
            $opciones = array(
                'cost' => 12
            );
            $password = password_hash($contra, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $opciones);

            $myquery = "call planevento.registrarCliente('$nombreC', '$apellidoP', '$apellidoM', '$fecha', '$telefono', '$correo', '$password', '$nombreImagen');";
```

//A partir de aquí no funciona, no se hace la query y se va directamente al else

```
            if ($conn->query($myquery)) {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'exito'
                );
            } else {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'error',
                    'query' => $myquery
                );
            }
            $conn->close();
            //$res = $conn->query($query);

            /*$respuesta = array(
                'respuesta' => $query
            );*/
            /*$fila = $res->fetch_assoc();

            if ($fila['@resultado'] == 2) {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'exito'
                );
            } else {
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'error'
                );
            }*/

            //$res->close();
        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $respuesta = array(
            'error' => $e->getMessage()
        );
    }
```

Mi conexión a la base de datos se llama $conn

Espero me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mira el log a ver si hay errores.... _y_ bienvenido.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver ha problema en el query:

```
$myquery = "call planevento.registrarCliente('$nombreC', '$apellidoP', '$apellidoM', '$fecha', '$telefono', '$correo', '$password', '$nombreImagen');";
```

cambialo por esto:

$myquery = "call planevento.registrarCliente('".$nombreC."','".$apellidoM."','".$fecha."',".$telefono.",'".$correo."','".$password."','".$nombreImagen."');";

PD. si no te funciona es porque el campo telefono no es numerico.

Comment: Tu propuesta tiene errores de comillas, revisa

Comment: Lo importante es darte la idea, cuando usas php combinado con mysql como lo estas haciendo tienes que tener en cuenta donde hay que abrir y cerrar comillas, ese es el problema por el cual no te ejecuta la consulta

Comment: Y no sería más simple corregir el error? Así la respuesta queda correcta para todos quienes consulten

Comment: ya hice la modificacion, creo que alli estaria bien.